# Under iOS12 system, the APP cannot display the picture normally

Tags: ios, sdwebimage, cgimage, ios12

My project, under the iOS12 system, loads the image and only shows part of it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4Bd6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onq5V.png)

The image format I loaded was Webp, and the framework I used was SDWebImage.

The error message that Xcode prompted me was ‘CGImageCreate: invalid image bits/component: 8 bits/pixel 24 alpha info = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is solved, because of the bugs generated using SDWebImage.

Refer to the related repair records https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/pull/2348

SDWebImage has been upgraded to 4.4.1 to solve the problem.